# How to put image and span tag in the same div to display their content on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have following code

```
  <div class="expense"><img class="money"/><span class="total"></span></div>
```

This produces the div and puts the image on one line and the content in span tag on other line. How can I put those on the same line?

Comment: This is pretty easy to find on the web.

Comment: @Ryan It is now, thanks to this user asking the question!

Comment: `<img ... style="vertical-align: middle;">` maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

css: `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`

Comment: Should I put this rule in Div? or in Span?

Comment: apply to both image and span

Comment: @Jeff yes, but unless you explicitly state it in css you can still end up with his situation.

Comment: really? Note also that the `display` property is not inherited

Comment: @Jeff yes html can be stupid like that, it also depends on the browser

Comment: @Jeff but I have had to fix this before with explicit statements

Comment: @ryan. jeff is correct. No browser by default will treat such elements as anything but inline. What tends to happen, is that `<img>` elements will be set to block via a reset stylesheet, and then needs to be restored back to inline on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do:

```
<div class="expense" style="display:table-row">
    <img class="money" style="display:table-cell" />
    <span class="total" style="display:table-cell"></span>
</div>
```

It's not the neatest, but it's another option

Answer (score 3):

You can use vertical-align : super to span.

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex:

```
.expense {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```