# Form Inline and Horizontal With image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to program a mixed form, horizontal and inline, with an image, but my bootstrap is not helping me.

Here is what I have:
[image]

Here is what I want:
[image]

And, finally, the code:

```
<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='foto' class='sr-only'>Foto</label>
                    <img class='fotoassociado' src='../../<?php if($sqlcmd->Foto == '') {echo 'photos/no_photo.jpg';} else {echo $sqlcmd->Foto;} ?>' />
                    <input type='file' class='form-control' name='foto' id='foto' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='nome' class='sr-only'>Nome</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='nome' id='nome' value='<?php echo $sqlcmd->Nome; ?>' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='email' class='sr-only'>E-mail</label>
                    <input type='email' class='form-control' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $sqlcmd->Email; ?>' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='rg' class='sr-only'>RG</label>
                    <input type='rg' class='form-control rg' name='rg' id='rg' value='<?php echo $sqlcmd->RG; ?>' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='cpf' class='sr-only'>CPF</label>
                    <input type='cpf' class='form-control cpf' name='cpf' id='cpf' value='<?php echo $sqlcmd->CPF; ?>' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='TelRes' class='sr-only'>Residencial</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='TelRes' id='TelRes' value='<?php echo $sqlcmd->TelResidencial; ?>' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='TelCom' class='sr-only'>Comercial</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='TelCom' id='TelCom' value='<?php echo $sqlcmd->TelComercial; ?>' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='TelCel' class='sr-only'>Celular</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='TelCel' id='TelCel' value='<?php echo $sqlcmd->TelCelular; ?>' />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
form.form-horizontal {
    float: right;
    width: 83%;
}
```

```html
   <head>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </head>  <body>
   <img class='fotoassociado' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloud.ohloh.net/attachments/72914/favicon_med.png' />
<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class='form-group' style="width: 80%;">
                    <label for='foto' class='sr-only'>Foto</label>
                    <input type='file' class='form-control' name='foto' id='foto' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'style="width: 80%;">
                    <label for='nome' class='sr-only'>Nome</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='nome' id='nome' value='name' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'style="width: 40%;display: -webkit-inline-box;">
                    <label for='email' class='sr-only'>E-mail</label>
                    <input type='email' class='form-control' name='email' id='email' value='Email' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group' style="width: 40%;display: -webkit-inline-box;">
                    <label for='rg' class='sr-only'>RG</label>
                    <input type='rg' class='form-control rg' name='rg' id='rg' value='RG' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group' style="width: 30%;display: -webkit-inline-box;">
                    <label for='cpf' class='sr-only'>CPF</label>
                    <input type='cpf' class='form-control cpf' name='cpf' id='cpf' value='cpf' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group' style="width: 30%;display: -webkit-inline-box;">
                    <label for='TelRes' class='sr-only'>Residencial</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='TelRes' id='TelRes' value='TEl' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group' style="width: 30%;display: -webkit-inline-box;">
                    <label for='TelCom' class='sr-only'>Comercial</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='TelCom' id='TelCom' value='telc' />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='TelCel' class='sr-only'>Celular</label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='TelCel' id='TelCel' value='telcal' />
                </div>
            </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try having, the image and the labels you want inline, under the tag `<span>`
>   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785450/how-to-put-image-and-span-tag-in-the-same-div-to-display-their-content-on-the-sa) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the image. For example:

```
.fotoassociado {
    float: left;
}
```

Or if you want that whole form group then you'll make that whole div float left, by either selecting the first form-group...

```
.form-group:first-of-type { 
    float: left;
 }
```

or by adding an additional class.

```
<div class='form-group float-left'>

.float-left {
    float: left;
 }
```